# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string - JS, PHP

Tags: javascript, php

у меня есть строка кода и в ней есть ошибка синтаксическая, вот она:

```
+"<td>" . date('d-m-Y', strtotime(ms[i].data)) .  "</td>" +
```

в этой строке мне подчеркивает `"</td>"`, и пишет: Ожидался идентификатор.ts(1003).
Браузер выдает ошибку Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string (и указывает на строку которую я написал вначале), сама строка написана в моем скрипте.js, может ли кто то мне помочь мне в правильном написании данной строки? Заранее спасибо.
Полный код:
Функция в которой выступает ошибка:

```
    function getNewMessages() {
        $.get("services/nowe_wiadomosci.php",
                function(data) {
                    console.log(data)
                    if (data != "brak") {
                        var ms = $.parseJSON(data);
                        for (i = 0; i < ms.length; i++) {
                            var row = $("<tr data-id='{$row['id']}' class='nieprzeczytana tr-border-top tr-border-bottom' style='height: 30px;'>" + 
                            "<td>" + ms[i].nadawca + "</td>" + 
                            "<td class='cursor-pointer'>" + ms[i].tytul + "</td>" + 
                            "<td>" . date('d-m-Y', strtotime(ms[i].data)) .  "</td>" +
                            // "<td>" + ms[i].data + "</td>" + 
                            "<td><button class='odpowiedzButton buttonmoon'>Odpowiedz</button></td>" + 
                            "<td><button class='przekazButton buttonmoon'>Przekaz</button></td>" + 
                            "<td>" +    
                                "<form action='services/zmiana_katalogu.php' method='post'>" +
                                "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='{$row['id']}'>" + 
                                "Katalog: " + 
                                "<select class='buttonmoon' name='select'>" +
                                "    <option selected='selected'>Odebrane</option>" + 
                                "    <option>Spam</option>" + 
                                "    <option>Kosz</option>" + 
                                "</select>" + 
                                "<input type='submit' name='katalog' id='katalog' class='buttonmoon zk' value='Zapisz' />" + 
                                "</form>" + 
                            "</td>" + 
                            "</tr>");
                            row.insertAfter($("#header"));
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    setInterval(getNewMessages, 1000);
```

Файл nowe_wiadomosci.php:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
?>
<?php 
                    $servername = "localhost";
                    $username = "root";
                    $password = "";
                    $dbname = "pocztadb";

                    $wlasciciel = $_SESSION["nick"];


                    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                    if ($conn->connect_error) {
                        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                    }
                    
                    $lastId = $_SESSION["lastId"];
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wiadomosci WHERE wlasciciel='$wlasciciel' AND
                            katalog='Odebrane' AND id > $lastId ORDER BY data";
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);
                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        $i = 0;
                        while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
                            $lastId = $row->id;
                            $ms[$i] = $row;
                            $i++;
                        }
                        $_SESSION["lastId"] = $lastId;
                     echo json_encode($ms);
                } else {
                    echo "brak";
                } 
                    


                        $conn->close();
                    ?>
```

Comment: А чего тут стоят точки? ``` . date('d-m-Y', strtotime(ms[i].data)) .```

Comment: Так как по другому функцию нельзя вставить, разве что можно еще с помощью {...}

Comment: Обычно JS вставляется так `let str = `"<td>" + ${alert('Hello world')} +  "</td>"`
. Т.е. нужно обернуть в одинарные обратные кавычки строку + к этому, JS код взять в ${....}. Что-то у меня не вышло с форматированием. В общем вот  в такие кавычки строку ``

Comment: @Макск мне в моей коде не нужно вызывать функцию jQuery c помощью ```$```

Comment: это не jQuery ))) это JS

Comment: Добавьте больше кода в вопрос.

Comment: @OliverPatterson сейчас добавлю

Comment: @Макск, экранировать бэктики (\`) тут можно обратным слэшем (\\) перед ними.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что эту часть генерит php?

Comment: @OliverPatterson уже разобрался, странно что никто даже не сказал, что функция date(strtotime()), это функция PHP, а я ее пытаюсь вызвать в скрипте.js